# How to get IP address of weblogic managed server using WLST

Tags: python, linux, weblogic, weblogic12c, wlst

I have a weblogic admin server and managed server. I am able to fetch the managed server name , its heap utilization etc from admin server using wlst. Now i would like to know if there is any way we can get the IP address of managed server using wlst scripts.

WLST script iam using

```
from datetime import datetime
from java.util import Date
from java.text import SimpleDateFormat
import os
import smtplib
import time
from java.io import File
from java.io import FileOutputStream
connect('weblogic','weblogic','t3://192.168.30.100:5011')
servers = domainRuntimeService.getServerRuntimes();

for server in servers:
        free    = int(server.getJVMRuntime().getHeapFreeCurrent())/(1024*1024)
        freePct = int(server.getJVMRuntime().getHeapFreePercent())
        #current = int(server.getJVMRuntime().getHeapSizeCurrent())/(1024*1024)
        #max     = int(server.getJVMRuntime().getHeapSizeMax())/(1024*1024)
        #print (server.getName(),current,free,max,freePct)
        print (server.getName(),freePct)
        print (server.getName(),free)
        heapfreepct = "/usr/local/bin/aws cloudwatch put-metric-data --metric-name 'Weblogic_heap_percent' --value '"+str(freePct)+"' --unit 'Percent' --namespace System/weblogic --dimensions InstanceId=$instanceid,weblogicInstance='"+str(server.getName())+"';"
        os.system(heapfreepct)
        heapsizefree = "/usr/local/bin/aws cloudwatch put-metric-data --metric-name 'Weblogic_heap_free' --value '"+str(free)+"' --unit 'Megabytes' --namespace System/weblogic --dimensions InstanceId=$instanceid,weblogicInstance='"+str(server.getName())+"';"
        os.system(heapsizefree)
disconnect()
exit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
server.getListenAddress()
```